# I have a table 't' with two columns 'col24' and 'col23' I want to create a data frame 'r'

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Imagine a table `t` with two columns -- `col24` and `col18`I want to make a data frame 'r'.So that the resulting data frame will have only one column `col24` called `first_name`.

I have tried the following code but it wont work.but I get it incorrect help me to solve

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

r = t.select(f.explode("col24").alias("first_name")).toPandas()
```

Comment: You have two columns `col24` and `col18`. 1) You want to rename `col24` to `first_name` 2) You want to drop `col18`. Is this what you want?

Comment: yes, I need the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
```

If I understood your question correctly, these two options should work:

```
r = t.select('col24').f.withColumnRenamed('col24', 'first_name')

r = t.withColumnRenamed('col24', 'first_name').drop('col18')
```

If you have multiple columns in a list **my_cols** for example, then second option becomes:

```
r = t.withColumnRenamed('col24', 'first_name').drop(*my_cols)
```

Then you can check your dataframe:

```
r.show()
```

or if t is massive, just check for columns names:

```
r.columns
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find your expected answer below:

```
select(f.col("col24").alias("first_name"))
```